# Why are these XElement collections being treated differently by XElement(XName, Object[])?

Tags: c#, xml, powershell

I do not understand why these are being treated differently by `XElement(XName, Object[])`

`using namespace System.Xml.Linq`

Version 1

```
$Test1 = @()
(0..2).foreach{ $Test1 += [XElement]::new("test", "test") }

$Query = [XElement]::new('root',[XElement]::new("parameters", $Test1)
)

$Query.ToString()
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <parameters>
    <test>test</test>
    <test>test</test>
    <test>test</test>
  </parameters>
</root>
```

---

Version 2

```
[Array]$Test2 = (0..2).foreach{ [XElement]::new("test", "test") }

$Query = [XElement]::new('root', [XElement]::new("parameters", $Test2)
)

$Query.ToString()
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <parameters>&lt;test&gt;test&lt;/test&gt;&lt;test&gt;test&lt;/test&gt;&lt;test&gt;test&lt;/test&gt;</parameters>
</root>
```

`$Test1.gettype()` and `$Test2.gettype()` both read as Arrays, and the objects they contain are all of type [XElement], with the same members.

They look identical, but they are treated differently. I realize that in Version 2 that without the type conversion to [Array], it would read as a type of [Collection`1].

Is that enough to cause problems?

What I've been able to determine:

```
[XElement]::new("Obj1", $test1[0], $test1[1], $test1[2]).ToString()
```

Behaves like version 1

```
[XElement]::new("Obj1", ($test1[0], $test1[1], $test1[2]) ).ToString()
```

Behaves like version 2

It's like it's converting the Version 2 [XElement] Array to a string, THEN processing it as a single XML String literal, which results in the encoding of the brackets.

(&lt and &gt)

---

EDIT:

THIS WORKS

```
$Array = foreach ($i in 1..3) { [XElement]::new("test", "test") }

$Query = [XElement]::new('root', [XElement]::new("parameters", $Array)
)

$Query.ToString()
```

Something about the `.foreach()` method in the process of mustering to a [collection'1] is causing the contents of the collection of Version 2 (regardless that it is cast to an array) to present the expanded text representation of the node, rather than passing the object representation to `XElement(XName, Object[])`.

Confusingly, when the XElement objects are sent to the console, it displays the object representation, but if you use `.psobject`:

You see that the BaseObject contains the expanded text representation of the nodes.

```
$test2.psobject 
BaseObject          : {<test>test</test>, <test>test</test>, <test>test</test>}
```

You see the node names for the BaseObject.

```
$test1.psobject
BaseObject          : {test, test, test}
```

You can ignore the $Query entirely and see that before they're even attempted to be added to the Root XMLTree that Powershell has already malformed `[XElement]` objects in the $Test2 collection.

I do not know what `.foreach()` is doing differently that the `foreach` keyword, most descriptions online equate them as being mostly identical in behavior. I will try and see what else I can find.

Comment: The first query has "+=" while second doesn't.  So first you are creating an array while second is just a combining the parameters without the tag names.

Comment: The second is also an array. You can verify this by using the gettype() method and accessing the values of the array by index.

Comment: Not an array of elements

Comment: How is $Test2 not an array of XElements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the data type of the array. The objects are being processed in a way that causes Powershell to behave as if they aren't of the `[XElement]` data type. Specifying this on the assignment variable as `[XElement[]]` ensures PS passes these along as parameters to other functions correctly.

```
[XElement[]]$array=(0..2).foreach{[XElement]::new("Name","$_")}
```

This is in part because of how the `.foreach()` operator behaves like a powershell script block that is executed with the `.invoke()` method.

```
$invoke={
[XElement]::new("Name","Value"),
[XElement]::new("Name","Value"),
[XElement]::new("Name","Value")
}.Invoke()
```

Behaves like

`$Array = (0..2).foreach{[XElement]::new("Name", "Value") }`

```
$invokereturnasis={
[XElement]::new("Name","Value"),
[XElement]::new("Name","Value"),
[XElement]::new("Name","Value")
}.InvokeReturnAsIs()
```

Behaves like

`$Array = (0..2) | ForEach-Object { [XElement]::new("Name", "Value") }`

[ForeEach-Object behavior Reference](https://powershell.one/tricks/performance/pipeline#how-it-works)

Other notes:

1. The `.foreach()` operator behaves like a scriptblock that is executed
   with the `.invoke()` method
2. You cannot force the `.foreach()` operator to use
   the `.InvokeReturnAsIs()` method.
3. The objects of the collection, when cast individually using
   `ForEach-Object` as `[XElement]` objects work as expected.

   `[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new("root", ( $Array | ForEach-Object {  [XElement]$_ } ))`

   Is valid

[Longer Explanation](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/chicanery-foreach-operator-causing-xelement-obj-to-change-output-behavior/#post-237118)

Comment: .foreach{} always returns a generic collection type. So you are using [xelement[]] to convert the collection to an array of xelement objects, which is the requirement nesting xelement nodes.

The foreach-object cmdlet implicitly assigns output to an array.

Answer (score 1):

So I jumped to the conclusion that @jdweng is right, the difference is all in the [Addition Assignment Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-operator#addition-assignment-operator-) `+=`. Then I saw your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62434284/why-are-these-xelement-collections-being-treated-differently-by-xelementxname#comment110423593_62434284), and thought, what do you mean, like @jdweng essentially said, that "well *of course* version 2 doesn't work because it's a single assignment, not an array of elements."

.... So I went forth to prove you wrong:

## Version 1

```
PS C:\> $Test1 = @()
PS C:\> (0..2).foreach{ $Test1 += [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new("test", "test") }
PS C:\> [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new('root',[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new("parameters", $Test1)).ToString()
<root>
  <parameters>
    <test>test</test>
    <test>test</test>
    <test>test</test>
  </parameters>
</root>

PS C:\> $test1.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

PS C:\> $test1.Count
3
```

Excellent. We know we have an array, and that it has 3 items. This is expected when we use the [Addition Assignment Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-operator#addition-assignment-operator-) `+=`. We are creating a new object, and Adding it to the existing `$Test1` array

Now, to prove you wrong. I feel so confident, that instead of casting to `[Array]`, I will even use the same [Array sub expression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7#the-array-sub-expression-operator) just to add salt to the wound:

## Version 2

```
PS C:\> $Test2 = @()
PS C:\> $Test2 = (0..2).foreach{ [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new("test", "test") }
PS C:\> [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new('root',[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new("parameters", $Test2)).ToString()
<root>
 <parameters>&lt;test&gt;test&lt;/test&gt;&lt;test&gt;test&lt;/test&gt;&lt;test&gt;test&lt;/test&gt;</parameters>
</root>
```

And now to prove you wrong:

```
PS C:\> $test2.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

PS C:\> $test2.Count
3
```

Oh...............

**They look exactly the same.** (Sweating)

They both are of type array. They both have a count of 3. You are right. This is a very valid question. They shouldn't be the "same" type both with 3 elements and output different results.

This requires further investigation. What exactly happens?

## Version 1

```
(0..2).foreach{ 
    $Test1 += [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new("test", "test") 
}
```

Breaking it down, how will the compiler interpret this statement?:

### Loop 1:

```
$Test1 += [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new("test", "test")
```

#### Result Loop 1:

```
$Test1[0] = <test>test</test>
```

### Loop 2:

```
$Test1 += [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new("test", "test")
```

#### Result Loop 2:

```
$Test1[0] = <test>test</test>
$Test1[1] = <test>test</test>
```

### Loop 3:

```
$Test1 += [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new("test", "test")
```

#### Result Loop 3:

```
$Test1[0] = <test>test</test>
$Test1[1] = <test>test</test>
$Test1[2] = <test>test</test>
```

This is your expected result.

Now let's look at the second version:

## Version 2

```
$Test2 = @()
$Test2 = (0..2).foreach{ [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new("test", "test") }
```

### Loop 1:

```
[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new("test", "test")
```

#### Result Loop 1:

```
<test>test</test>
```

### Loop 2:

```
[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new("test", "test")
```

#### Result Loop 2:

```
<test>test</test><test>test</test>
```

### Loop 3:

```
[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new("test", "test")
```

#### Result Loop 3:

```
<test>test</test><test>test</test><test>test</test>
```

### Final Assignment

```
$Test2 = <test>test</test><test>test</test><test>test</test>
```

Instead of adding additional array items to the array, you are pre-building your elements, *then* assigning it to the array.

We can see it better when we look at the elements themselves:

```
PS C:\> $test1 |select Name,NodeType,Value,NextNode,PreviousNode,Parent


Name         : test
NodeType     : Element
Value        : test
NextNode     : <test>test</test>
PreviousNode :
Parent       : <parameters>
                 <test>test</test>
                 <test>test</test>
                 <test>test</test>
               </parameters>

Name         : test
NodeType     : Element
Value        : test
NextNode     : <test>test</test>
PreviousNode : <test>test</test>
Parent       : <parameters>
                 <test>test</test>
                 <test>test</test>
                 <test>test</test>
               </parameters>

Name         : test
NodeType     : Element
Value        : test
NextNode     :
PreviousNode : <test>test</test>
Parent       : <parameters>
                 <test>test</test>
                 <test>test</test>
                 <test>test</test>
               </parameters>
```

Notice that by adding to the array, it fully built out each individual node. Each "new" Element was added individually, and built out the full "proper" Tree. and what about Test2?

```
PS C:\> $test2 |select Name,NodeType,Value,NextNode,PreviousNode,Parent


Name         : test
NodeType     : Element
Value        : test
NextNode     :
PreviousNode :
Parent       :

Name         : test
NodeType     : Element
Value        : test
NextNode     :
PreviousNode :
Parent       :

Name         : test
NodeType     : Element
Value        : test
NextNode     :
PreviousNode :
Parent       :
```

Notice that it didn't build out the tree. This is ***Flat***. It is 3 elements in a row. *That is why we get a count of 3*. That is why it is still an "array", and "looks" the same, but it is not. There is no Next Node or Previous Node, the XML hierarchical structure is not created.

This lack of structure means that when you try to build out the rest of the XML document, the `$Test2` array falls back to being interpreted as a plain string, instead of proper XML.

---

TLDR:

Add elements one at a time using `+=` or `.Add()`. This ensures that the new object you are creating is added properly. You create 3 **new** objects, directly add 3 new object references.

Vs. Test 2: You are creating 3 new objects, combining the **outputs** of the objects (not the references), then assigning the **outputs** of the 3 objects to the array, gives you different results.